# Error in running fixSUPEE6788.php

Tags: patches

I have downloaded this file from https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox
and have kept in root of my project but when I try to run command.

```
php -f fixSUPEE6788.php -- analyze
```

Then I get error in ssh.

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(./abstract.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/fixSUPEE6788.php on line 28
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './abstract.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/fixSUPEE6788.php on line 28
```

What is that which I am missing. I need to resolve 404 error for custom modules which came after installing patch.
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the file into the shell folder and run it from there

```
mv fixSUPEE6788.php ./shell

cd shell

php -f fixSUPEE6788.php -- analyze
```

Comment: please let me know the location of shell

Comment: Shell is in your magento root folder eg if your installed at /var/www/, then it will be at /var/www/shell

Comment: Do you know that how to run this command in local windows: this gives php: command not found in git bash.